# get historical data from youtube/instagram/spotify/twitter

Tags: twitter, youtube-data-api, spotify, instagram-api

I am searching for historical data (last 3-4 years) from youtube/instagram/spotify/twitter.
The goal is to compare the development of views/subsription/likes over time for about 500 accounts/channels. Monthly data would be perfectly fine.

From looking at some of the APIs, it is only possible to get the data of the day. Socialblade gives you in some cases the data for the last month. 
Is there an API or a Service that would help this task ?

Answer (score 0):

For Twitter https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/batch-historical/overview

For Youtube https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/#choose-the-right-api-for-your-application

For Instagram https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

I don't think this kind of data is available for Spotify  https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/users-profile/